# Zend Framework Mysql WHERE IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, where-in

Using the zend framework i have used a query,having a IN clause,this is my query

```
       $select->where('p.brandid  IN (?)',$details[brand]);
```

in the above query, $details[brand] has a value like this array(1,2,3) .

Actually the query has to return all the values which are all related to this  array(1,2,3).

But my query is returning the result related to the first value present in the above array(1,2,3).ie 1 alone other 2,3 is not considered.

when i print this query it shows like this

```
             [where] => Array
               (
                [0] => (p.brandid  IN ('1,2,3'))
              )
```

Can anyone show me what is the mistake i have made or solution for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your query is getting formed wrongly   `p.brandid  IN ('1,2,3')` instead of `p.brandid  IN (1,2,3)` you can try using implode function in php

```
$select->where('p.brandid  IN (?)',implode(",",$details[brand]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just small research, because I have the same problem.

I am not sure what version of Zend do you use. But solution provided by @Omesh doesn't work with my version 1.12.

In my case it is absolutely opposite `explode` solution:

```
$select->where('p.brandid  IN (?)', explode(',',$details[brand]));
```

Probably it depends on the type of `$details['brand']`. In my case I have string like `555,666,777,877`. But even if you have array there. That is strange if Zend accept in your case `string` (result of `implode`) and does not accept `array`. And in my case it does not accept `string` but accept `array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this according to Zend framwork

```
locate(concat(',',$details[brand],','),concat(',',p.brandid,','))>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$select->where->in('field_name', $your_simple_array);
```

If you using `where()` function with something criteria before, like

```
$select->where(['field_name' => $value]);
```

just use the first one after it, like

```
$select->where(['field_name' => $value]);
$select->where->in('field_name', $your_simple_array);
```

Always remember to use `where` not as a function `where()`, but just as a keyword.

This is valid and tested by me in the following context:

```
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select()->where(['field1' => $v1, 'field2' => $v2]);
$select->where->in('field_name', ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']);
```

That is, using these libraries in the beginning of the model class:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;
```